# Android SharedPref edit not working

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Got this code, which basicly updates my textviews depending on how far the user is in the quiz, which is stored in sharedPrefs. But when the correct answer is entered the prefs doesn't update. Does the commit() need too long time to set the prefs, so the activity calls the method setText() before the sharedPrefs are updated or what am i doing wrong?

```
private void setText() {
    SharedPreferences score = this.getSharedPreferences("football", MODE_PRIVATE);
    questionNumber = score.getInt("football", 0);
    question.setText(questions.get(questionNumber).get(0));
}

public void onClick(View v) {
switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bCheckAnswer:
        if (questions.get(questionNumber).contains(etAnswer.getText().toString())) {
            Integer newQ = questionNumber += 1;
            SharedPreferences change = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = change.edit();
            editor.putInt("football", newQ);
            editor.commit();
            setText();
        }else{
            question.setText("error occured");
        }
        break;
}
```

Comment: Why dont you open the "football" shared preference object the second time?

Comment: The answer from mike yaworski should fix your problem. Just to explain - preferences are stored in XML files. When you call `getSharedPreferences("football", MODE_PRIVATE);` it uses a file called `footbal.xml` (creating it if it needs to). The `getPreference(...)` method is a convenience method which simply calls `getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)` and passes in the `Activity` class name as the 'name' parameter, e.g., `MyActivity`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not opening the SharedPreference the same way when setting and getting.

Change this:

```
SharedPreferences change = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to this:

```
SharedPreferences change = this.getSharedPreferences("football", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Notice the differences:

- `getPreferences` vs `getSharedPreferences`
- you didn't give the preference reference as `"football"`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the prefs doesn't get updated or is it just that your textview isn't getting updated?  If this is being done in your Activity, you should not be changing layout (your text view) from within the Activity. You should use a Handler to make UI changes.